# WebRequest is Retrieving different HTML than the Browser

Tags: c#, html, webrequest

**Problem**

The html page retrieved by my c# web request is different than the one i get using the browser.

**Details**

I am trying to get the HTML of the page referenced by this URL :

```
https://sistemas.usp.br/jupiterweb/listarGradeCurricular?codcg=12&codcur=12012&codhab=1&tipo=N
```

The code i am using for the WebRequest is this one :

```
public string HttpsGet (string url)
{
    string response = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        HttpWebRequest WReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://uspdigital.usp.br/jupiterweb/listarGradeCurricular?codcg=9&codcur=9012&codhab=100&tipo=N");
        WReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

        try
        {
            WReq.Proxy = new WebProxy();
            WReq.Method = "GET";
            WReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1";
            WReq.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 800;
            WReq.Timeout = 80000;
            WReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            WReq.Referer = "";
            WReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)WReq.GetResponse();
            using (resp)
            {
                response = (new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Exception ex = exception;
        }
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("URL is empty or null");
    }
}
```

**How i figured out they were different**

I pasted both the html retrieved from code and the one from the browser (view source code on chrome) on notepad++.

After that, i managed to "count" (ctrl+f -> count) this string "#CCCCCC", which represents
the background color for some table rows.

The webrequest one gives me a count of 17 while the browser one gives me a count of 14.

Also, the "Course" of each page is different : The webrequest course is "Faculdade de Ciências Farmacêuticas" while the one on browser is "Faculdade de Economia, Administração e Contabilidade"  (these names are in portuguese).

**TL:DR**

Don't know why, the get on this link : `https://uspdigital.usp.br/jupiterweb/listarGradeCurricular?codcg=12&codcur=12012&codhab=1&tipo=N` gives me a different page in the webrequest c# compared to the result when i copy and paste it on the browser.

**Updates**

1. I tried to compare the User Agent from both requests, and they Match.
2. I figured out that the web request via C#, always gives me the same page, which is the page of the "Faculdade de Ciências Farmacêuticas" Course

I am guessing that there is something to do with the HTTPS thing.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long post

Comment: The user agent you're specifying - is it the same as they one you're using to view in a browser? I would guess the server at uspdigital.usp.br returns different views dependent on the browser?

Answer (score 4):

Find out the user agent string of your browser and then set the user agent string on your WebRequest to match. Many sites serve variant content/markup/styles/scripts based on the UA.

**UPDATE**

If you are using an HttpWebRequest, you can set the UA by the UserAgent property.

Comment: Can i use Fiddler to debug the request and use the same user agent ?

Comment: You should also check cookies from your site. They can affect generated content as well.

Comment: Not sure what Fiddler is, but if it reliably provides the UA, then do it to it. You can also detect it (and output it) using a little javascript.

Comment: Good point also, Dmitry. I was assuming unauthenticated, and not thinking about 3rd party cookies and the like.

Comment: I just checked the UA, and pasted it on my webrequest, it was the same i was using btw.

About the cookies, i am storing all the cookies of previously requests, but it still not working.

The COURSE retrieved is different on the Browser and on the WebRequest C#. Not only the Page structure, the content is also different.

Comment: Try capturing the actual request from the browser, and then try doing the same with the request from .NET. Compare the two and see if they are indeed identical. If they aren't, try to get them to the point that they are. If you still have differences, it has to be some type of cookie-related issue.

Comment: The web request via C#, always gives me the same page, which is the page of the "Faculdade de Ciências Farmacêuticas" Course.

Comment: You're talking about the response. I'm talking about the request. I don't mean "capture the html in the response". I mean "capture the entire http request sent from the browser and the entire http request sent from code".

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Host to `uspdigital.usp.br` and replacing the word "sistemas" to "uspdigital" on the url seems to work for me.